# One word in Sinhala in an English document using LaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, languages

Is there a way to write just one word in Sinhala in otherwise English document using LaTeX? I am using Overleaf

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pick a font with the characters,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\sfont{Noto Serif Sinhala}
\begin{document}

Some english text {\sfont එක වචනයක්} some more english
\end{document}
```

Compile using xelatex (as you tagged) or lualatex.

Comment: You took that very literally, it seems ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht well i needed some example:-)

Comment: එක වචනයක් seems very dope in Sinhala language!